# Google visualization geomap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, dom-events

I know from reading the assoc. [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-visualization-api/K8uJoes8ZH0) that there is not currently an event for clicking a specific point when using the marker map (only `regionClick` is implemented).

But was reading the docs and noticed the event `Select` which says:

> select     Fired when the user clicks a visual entity. To learn what has
> been selected, call getSelection().   None

and

> setSelection()    none     Selects the specified chart entities. Cancels any
> previous selection. Selectable entities are regions with an assigned
> value. A region correlates to a row in the data table (column index is
> null). For this chart, only one entity can be selected at a time.
> Extended description.

Would I be able to use this to get the entry that was clicked?

Example:

```
       data.addRows([
        ['Rome', 2761477, 1285.31],
        ['Milan', 1324110, 181.76],
        ['Naples', 959574, 117.27],
        ['Turin', 907563, 130.17],
        ['Palermo', 655875, 158.9],
        ['Genoa', 607906, 243.60],
        ['Bologna', 380181, 140.7],
        ['Florence', 371282, 102.41]
      ]);
```

Somehow get that Milan was clicked?  How would I do this?  Or am I reading this wrong?

Google API for Geomaps: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html

Google Group stating there is no click event in Marker mode:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-visualization-api/K8uJoes8ZH0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need call [getSelection](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#visgetselection) function when the select event is called. This function returns an array of objects. Each object have row and column attributes (if any). Use the row and the first column (0) to retrieve the label name (Rome, Milan, ...).

Example (http://jsfiddle.net/VtZQh/):

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection()[0];
  var label = data.getValue(selection.row, 0);
  alert(label);
});
```

Please refer to documentation to know more about `getSelection`.